# Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread

Tags: ios, mbprogresshud

**Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
1   0x5122fe9 WebThreadLock
2   0x17dfcf5 -[UIFieldEditor becomeFieldEditorForView:]
.
.
.
.**

Im getting this error even when im using..  **[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];** ... method
 Im using MBProgressHUD... im getting this error message in 2nd alertview.

This link http://www.zebpedersen.co.uk/?p=1850 helped me to solve this error. If I use this im not getting progress view... progressHUD is mandatory..

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in Main thread like below.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [self doSomething];
});
```